# The number of solutions of $\sin(x) + 2\sin(2x) + 3\sin(3x) + 4\sin(4x) = 10$ in $( 0 , \pi )$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find the number of solutions in $( 0 , \pi )$ of the equation
>   $$\sin(x) + 2\sin(2x) + 3\sin(3x) + 4\sin(4x) = 10.$$

I have no idea about how to approach this problem . I thought of converting everything into $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ but that would be too long and make it more complex .

Comment: Hint: $1+2+3+4 = 10$

Comment: @Ricky I have edited your question, please check that my edit is correct.

Comment: @fvel Sorry , I cant proceed . Can you please answer it .

Comment: [Note](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2B2sin%282x%29%2B3sin%283x%29%2B4sin%284x%29-10%3D0) that complex solution seems to exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you know

$$\matrix{
   {0 \le \sin (x) \le 1,} & {0 \le x  \le \pi }  \cr 
 } $$

and hence

$$0 \le \sin(x) + 2\sin(2x) + 3\sin(3x) + 4\sin(4x) \le 10$$

and we can have your equality **only** when all of the $\sin$'s are equal to $1$, i.e,

$$\matrix{
   {\sin (x) = 1} \hfill &  \to  \hfill & {x = {\pi  \over 2}} \hfill  \cr 
   {\sin (2x) = 1} \hfill &  \to  \hfill & {x = {\pi  \over 4}} \hfill  \cr 
   {\sin (3x) = 1} \hfill &  \to  \hfill & {x = {\pi  \over 6},{{5\pi } \over 6}} \hfill  \cr 
   {\sin (4x) = 1} \hfill &  \to  \hfill & {x = {\pi  \over 8},{{5\pi } \over 8}} \hfill  \cr 
 } $$

However, this is impossible because this leads to different values for $x \in (0,\pi)$ at the same time. So the number of solutions is **zero**.

Comment: @Ricky: Did you get it? :)

Comment: Surely there are more values where sin 4x = 1 other than x = pi/8?

Comment: @gnasher729: Fixed that! :)

Comment: @H.R. Yup . Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The given equation will not satisfy because max value 1 for each is required which is there for different angles for each of them therefore at a particular angle all of them cannot get maximum value